# Dynamic Router URI in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm following chapter 8 of "Camel in Action" book and testing with Dynamic router. I have defined two routes as below:

```
from("direct:start")
.dynamicRouter(method(DynamicRouterBean.class, "route"))
.log("dynamicRoute result = ${body}");

from("seda:a")
.log("In direct:a with message ${body}");
```

And in the DynamicRouterBean's route method, I have implemented route logic as follows:

```
public String route(String body, @Header(Exchange.SLIP_ENDPOINT) String previous) {
    System.out.println("Enter DynamicRouterBean, body=" + body + ", previous=" + previous);
    if (previous == null) {
        return "seda://a";
    } else if ("seda://a".equals(previous)) {
        return "language://simple:Bye ${body}";
    } else {
        // no more, so return null to indicate end of dynamic router
        return null;
    }
}
```

The code works as the book described... but the issue I recognized is that if I return endpoint URI without double slash "//" in the middle in the route method, the second condition to check previous equals "seda:a" will fail and so the dynamic route will stop there

```
if (previous == null) {
        return "seda:a";
    } else if ("seda:a".equals(previous)) {
        // This condition will not match... and it will return null
        return "language:simple:Bye ${body}";
    } else {
        // no more, so return null to indicate end of dynamic router
        return null;
    }
```

Is it a feature that Camel's DynamicRouter require the addition of "//" in the middle of the URI? I search around the book or the Camel official website but seem not mentioned about this... If yes, any reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes endpoints in Camel are formatted as `name://context-path?options` eg with those double slashes. So if you compare then to as in the book.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... just want to double confirm... the Dynamic routers will re-format those endpoints URI with double slashes automatically? I downloaded the Camel in action sample codes from https://github.com/camelinaction/camelinaction, most of the sample code use URI without double slashes, except the DynamicRouterBean sample

Comment: Yes eg when Camel provides the previous parameter above, eg its Camel providing that, not you that has hardcoded the value. When you specific an uri you can omit the double slashes.